# How to Hide Cell in UITableView That was created in storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I need to hide a cell if a condition does not exist.  Just setting cell.isHidden does not work, so the only other option I could find was setting the hightForRowAt to 0.   This visually works fine but triggers a console warning:   How can I hide the cell without triggering this warning all the time?

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282346080 UIView:0x104dbdb40.centerY == UITableViewCellContentView:0x104d22140.centerY   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2823460d0 V:|-(11)-[UIView:0x104dbdb40]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x104d22140 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282370320 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x104d22140.height == 0   (active)>"
)


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   
    var rowHeight: CGFloat = 200
    
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            rowHeight = 125
        case 1:
            rowHeight = 97
        case 2:
            if let workoutLocations = Metadata.workoutLocations {
                if workoutLocations.count > 0 {
                    // rowHeight = 200
                    rowHeight = 220
                } else {
                    return 0
                }
            } else { return 0}
        case 3:
            rowHeight = 446
        case 4:
            rowHeight = 302
        case 5:
            rowHeight = 302
        case 6:
            rowHeight = 162
        case 7:
            rowHeight = 192
        default: ()
        }
    default: ()
    }

return rowHeight
```

}

Comment: It looks like you have a vertical spacing constraint equal to 11.  Does it help to make that <= 11?

Comment: @PhillipMills no i tried but pretty much any constraints trigger the warning, maybe if I connect them to IBOutlet and 1 by 1 delete them? 

Comment: @GarySabo - are you designing ***static cells*** in your Storyboard? Or, did you design a Prototype cell the you are reusing?

Comment: @DonMag these are static cells

Comment: @omerfarukozturk I don't think that would work with static cells?  Wouldn't cellForRowAt override my cells in the storyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have the UI elements in your cell constrained to the cell's `contentView`? If so...

Select the element that has a **Bottom** constraint to the bottom of the content view, and change that constraint's priority:

[image]

Comment: Wow, works perfect!   Thanks for taking the time 